# Determine all intervals of numbers $x$ satisfying the following inequalities.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

i) $(x-5)^2 (x+10)\leq 0$

ii) $(x-5)^4 (x+10) \leq 0$

**My answer :** i) $(-10)\leq x \leq (5)$.

ii) $(-10)\leq x \leq (5)$.

*Can you check my answer?*

Comment: BTW if the only thing you need is to check whether your answer is correct or not, for many simple problems you can simply [ask WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x-5)%5E2(x%2B10)%3C%3D0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intervals seem too big: For example, in i, we have $(4-5)^2(4+10) = 4+10 > 0$.

The correct solution is as follows: For i to hold, one of the factors has to be zero, or the factors have to have opposite signs. Since the first factor is a square and therefore nonnegative, that means that $x-5=0$ or $x+10 \leq 0$ must hold, so the two intervals are $(-\infty, -10]$ and $[5, 5]$.

Since the sign of $(x-5)^4$ is the same as the sign of $(x-5)^2$, the solution to ii is the same